# Tradeoffs of an 'access network' with 30 bit subnet mask

Tags: routing, switch, subnet

I've got fiber lines coming into my office, with IP setup like so:

Access Network 123.123.123.20/30
Our Router: 123.123.123.21
ISP Router: 123.123.123.22

At the moment the router is taking the fiber in and acting as a gateway, but I'm considering taking an SFP and putting it in a switch before the router [on its own vlan] to make the network more flexible. Are there any dangers to doing so with such a contrained ip space? Is there other benefits for widening this access network? Are ISPs keen on doing so?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

**The /30 only provides two useable host addresses** and your router and the ISP have consumed them.  This net block is commonly known as the WAN block from your ISP and is used for just that link.  For the access side, you should have a separate (public) LAN block provided to you by the ISP.  This could be as small as a /29 or to a /24 or larger, depending on your needs (with justification).

The LAN block is where you should be concentrating your "access network".  On this side of the fence, you place your firewall or other publicly facing devices here that should be protected from the Internet.

```
user1 \
user2  -- sw [private lan] -- fw -- [public lan] -- rtr [wan /30] -- ISP -- Internet
user3 /
```

Comment: In this diagram either the FW or the router would be performing NAT.  If the FW is completing the NAT function, then the inclusion of the router is unnecessary since the larger public IP space would just be routed directly to the FW by the ISP.

Comment: @cpt_fink, I made the assumption that the existing router was there to stay and wanted to show a more complete view of an enterprise stack with firewall as I don't know if OP has that or even if the router is capable of it.  The OP is certainly welcome to combine logical functions into physical devices.  Personally, I deploy small branch offices without redundancy similar to this stack to fit a standard design and to add those redundant devices later.  I run BGP with MPLS-lite on the router with EIGRP redistribution with the firewall.